# qt sqlite3 prerequisites

Tags: qt, sqlite

I'm writing a small app in qt that is to access some data in an sqlite database and stick it in a table. I'm completely new to qt and darn rusty with c++ so brace yourselves for a potentially stupid question...

So I have a QTableView and a database. I found a lovely little example at http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qsqlquerymodel.html#details that I will reproduce here for convenience:

```
 QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
 model->setQuery("SELECT name, salary FROM employee");
 model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
 model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Salary"));

 QTableView *view = new QTableView;
 view->setModel(model);
 view->show();
```

Looks nice and simple. But alas! It turns out that the qt installer i used (for 32 bit windows) seems to not include the necessary libraries. So I started looking for them. Once I had the QSqlQueryModel class down I found that it had a load of dependencies too. So I hit the gitorious repo where everything is stored and subsequently found out that if I want to use the sqlite stuff I need to run 'configure' in order to enable the database driver i'm interested in before building the source.

I wondered around my qt installation directory a bit and there are some sql related dlls, I dont know what's in them though.

So the question is, how do I get sqlite and qt talking nicely if i want to use qtCreator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done a Windows build but as far as I know it should prebuild the SQLite files, but I have a feeling it only does the SQLite2 ones.

[If you've tried the Qt instructions on building the driver](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qsqlite-plugin) and it's still being a pain just make sure you've got the sqlite libraries, head into the applications folder and look for plugins/sqldrivers and there'll be a .pro file in there to compile the drivers, you should be able to build that from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The Qt SQLite plugin is one of the two SQL driver plugins (with ODBC) you don't need to compile and install yourself because it is already included in the QtSDK.

But the code from QSqlQueryModel doesn't include the database connection, so you should look at the more complete examples installed in the QtSDK\Examples folder (with some explanation there: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/examples-sql.html ).